# Python3 Make tie-breaking lambda sort more pythonic?

Tags: sorting, python-3.x, lambda

As an exercise in python lambdas (just so I can learn how to use them more properly) I gave myself an assignment to sort some strings based on something other than their natural string order.

I scraped apache for version number strings and then came up with a lambda to sort them based on numbers I extracted with regexes. It works, but I think it can be better I just don't know how to improve it so it's more robust.

```
from lxml import html
import requests
import re

# Send GET request to page and parse it into a list of html links
jmeter_archive_url='https://archive.apache.org/dist/jmeter/binaries/'
jmeter_archive_get=requests.get(url=jmeter_archive_url)
page_tree=html.fromstring(jmeter_archive_get.text)
list_of_links=page_tree.xpath('//a[@href]/text()')

# Filter out all the non-md5s. There are a lot of links, and ultimately
# it's more data than needed for his exercise
jmeter_md5_list=list(filter(lambda x: x.endswith('.tgz.md5'), list_of_links))

# Here's where the 'magic' happens. We use two different regexes to rip the first
# and then the second number out of the string and turn them into integers. We
# then return them in the order we grabbed them, allowing us to tie break.
jmeter_md5_list.sort(key=lambda val: (int(re.search('(\d+)\.\d+', val).group(1)), int(re.search('\d+\.(\d+)', val).group(1))))
print(jmeter_md5_list)
```

This does have the desired effect, The output is:

`['jakarta-jmeter-2.5.1.tgz.md5', 'apache-jmeter-2.6.tgz.md5', 'apache-jmeter-2.7.tgz.md5', 'apache-jmeter-2.8.tgz.md5', 'apache-jmeter-2.9.tgz.md5', 'apache-jmeter-2.10.tgz.md5', 'apache-jmeter-2.11.tgz.md5', 'apache-jmeter-2.12.tgz.md5', 'apache-jmeter-2.13.tgz.md5']`

So we can see that the strings are sorted into an order that makes sense. Lowest version first and highest version last. Immediate problems that I see with my solution are two-fold.

- First, we have to create two different regexes to get the numbers we want instead of just capturing groups 1 and 2. Mainly because I know there are no multiline lambdas, I don't know how to reuse a single regex object instead of creating a second.
- Secondly, this only works as long as the version numbers are two numbers separated by a single period. The first element is 2.5.1, which is sorted into the correct place but the current method wouldn't know how to tie break for 2.5.2, or 2.5.3, or for any string with an arbitrary number of version points.

So it works, but there's got to be a better way to do it. How can I improve this?

Comment: Poor use of a a lambda. It is more 'Pythonic' to just write a little function for this.

Comment: @dawg Thank you, but that was already addressed in Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Originally, I came up with this:

```
jmeter_md5_list.sort(key=lambda val: list(map(int, re.compile('(\d+(?!$))').findall(val))))
```

However, based on Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams's answer, I made the following changes.

```
def sortable_key_from_string(value):
        version_tuple = tuple(map(int, re.compile('(\d+(?!$))').findall(value)))
        match = re.match('^(\D+)', value)
        version_name = ''
        if match:
                version_name = match.group(1)
        return (version_tuple, version_name)
```

and this:

```
jmeter_md5_list.sort(key = lambda val: sortable_key_from_string(val))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a full answer, but it will get you far along the road to one.

The return value of the key function can be a tuple, and tuples sort naturally. You want the output from the key function to be:

```
((2, 5, 1), 'jakarta-jmeter')
((2, 6), 'apache-jmeter')
etc.
```

Do note that this is a poor use case for a lambda regardless.

Comment: You replied while I was giving my own answer. I see what you're saying. What is the proper decorum? Should I update my own answer to match what you are saying or should I make my changes and then post them as a comment to yours?